# Hyper parameters (window size and vector dimensions) tuning in word2vec using Grey Wolf Optimization

Tags: optimization, word-embeddings, word2vec, hyperparameter-tuning

Using Grey wolf Optimization, I want to calculate optimal values of two hyper parameters: context window size and embedding size (vector dimensions) for word2vec skipgram model used for word embedding. I want to use this model to find top 25 similar words of a token. But I don't know how to apply GWO to this problem.